# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement | ReferenceError:[function] is not defined

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, referenceerror

I'm getting a error in the code that previously worked fine. Im not sure if I have made any changes to it.

Error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Code Snippet:

```
function ChangeOptions() {
var x = document.getElementById("Select1").value;
var y = document.getElementById("Select2");
var z = document.getElementById("Select3");

 if(x == "Sch"){y.innerHTML = "<option value="Sch1">Sch1</option><option  value="Sch1">Sch2</option>"; 
                z.innerHTML = "<option value="1">1</option><option value="1" value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>";}
if(x == "COMM"){y.innerHTML = "<option value="COMM1">COMM1</option><option value="COMM2">COMM2</option>"; 
                z.innerHTML = "<option value="1-4">1-4</option><option value="5-7">5-7</option><option value="8-10">8-10</option>";}
if(x == "Inst"){y.innerHTML = "<option value="Inst1">Inst1</option><option value="Inst2">Inst2</option>"; 
                z.innerHTML = "<option value="1-4">1-4</option><option value="5-7">5-7</option><option value="8-10">8-10</option>";} 
}
```

When I initially load my site i get this error in the console. If i click on the select button in my html which calls this function on *onchange* event, then I get a error

> ReferenceError: ChangeOptions is not defined

But, when I remove the conditional operators(ifs) then I don't get the *ReferenceError: ChangeOptions is not defined*

Can someone please guide me through this?

Comment: That's an "interesting" indenting scheme you're using.

Comment: A bit like the ad-hoc adherence to grammatical rules? :)

Comment: The way the code is formatted in Jonathan's answer is more usual, and most people will find it easier to read.

Comment: oK, Sorry!! Will surely keep it in mind! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strings are getting torn apart by the inner double quotes. Use single quotes on the outside or escape the inner quotes using a backslash.

E.g. `"This is a \"valid\" string"` or `'This is a "valid" string'` too.

Just a gotcha - use triple equals for exact equality. Unless you *know* the exact reason to use double equals equality matching, don't. That is my 2 cents.

```
function ChangeOptions() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Select1").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("Select2");
  var z = document.getElementById("Select3");

  if (x === "Sch") {
    y.innerHTML = '<option value="Sch1">Sch1</option><option  value="Sch1">Sch2</option>';
    z.innerHTML = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="1" value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>';
  }
  if (x === "COMM") {
    y.innerHTML = '<option value="COMM1">COMM1</option><option value="COMM2">COMM2</option>';
    z.innerHTML = '<option value="1-4">1-4</option><option value="5-7">5-7</option><option value="8-10">8-10</option>';
  }
  if (x === "Inst") {
    y.innerHTML = '<option value="Inst1">Inst1</option><option value="Inst2">Inst2</option>';
    z.innerHTML = '<option value="1-4">1-4</option><option value="5-7">5-7</option><option value="8-10">8-10</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: @RohitNair don't forget to accept an answer (even if not mine!)

Answer (score 0):

Few issues I see here. You'll need to escape the inside double quotes, or better use single quotes for strings outside.

```
    function ChangeOptions() {
      var x = document.getElementById("Select1").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("Select2");
      var z = document.getElementById("Select3");

      if(x == "Sch"){
        y.innerHTML = '<option value="Sch1">Sch1</option><option  value="Sch1">Sch2</option>';
        z.innerHTML = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="1" value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>';
      }      
     if(x == "COMM") {
       y.innerHTML = '<option value="COMM1">COMM1</option><option value="COMM2">COMM2</option>';
       z.innerHTML = '<option value="1-4">1-4</option><option value="5-7">5-7</option><option value="8-10">8-10</option>';
     }
     if(x == "Inst") {
       y.innerHTML = '<option value="Inst1">Inst1</option><option value="Inst2">Inst2</option>';
       z.innerHTML = '<option value="1-4">1-4</option><option value="5-7">5-7</option><option value="8-10">8-10</option>';
     }
   }
```